# iframe set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin' social-tables

Tags: social-tables

For getting authorization code , the flow goes to email/password page of social tables. I am trying to load that page in an iframe.
Gives below error message:
Refused to display 'https://auth.socialtables.com/login?redirect=/oauth/authorize?client_id=xxxxx..' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

- Is there a anyway i can override this option so that it gets
  displayed in iframe?
- Is there another way to display this page
  within my application?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, we don't have iframe's enabled for our login page. The recommended way is to have the Social Tables login page page open in a new tab (or in current page) and set the redirect_url to the page the user was currently on within your app. That would be the easiest method.

I'll submit a request for comments for this feature to be available in the meantime.

Comment: is the redirect_url not fixed while creating an app in social-tables? Can a different url be given each time so that user can return to that page where he was when he clicked on social-tables?

Comment: Second question: is there a way i can send multiple parameters in redirect_url? Let me know if social-tables authorization server supports "state" param?

Comment: Hi @Manmeet - You can set the redirect_uri to any url you want on each call. But you need to make sure you call the `/oauth/token` endpoint to get the users oauth token before you make any subsequent api calls.

Comment: As for your second question, yes query params should be supported in the redirect url. I assume you mean, for example, `redirect_uri=https://my-domain.com?query=1&query2=2&query3=3`?

As long as you encode the URI component to escape the characters, it will work

Comment: Can you give an example..Right now if in app it is not set or set to some value and i send different url it gives message as :{"message":"redirect_uri does not match"}

Comment: Ah, I see the issue. It does appear that the redirect_uri that you put in the query string needs to match the URI you configured in the developer portal.

You will need to have those two match. You can then handle the redirect back to the page your users were on within your app by storing it either in session or some other mechanism on your end.